# Strange green pixels in decoded output of FFmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-processing, hevc

I tried decoding a HEVC encoded bitstream. I dropped some slice NAL units to see concealment in existing FFmpeg decoder for HEVC videos. What I see is a green patch overlay over some pixels. These green patches are not completely green, this makes me wonder if concealment is taking place or not. I tried '-ec 0' option but it still gives same output. I am attaching the output I got. Please help if someone has observed it and is able to solve.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4unoY.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is my experience from HM and JSVM, not FFMPEG:

Try smaller packet loss rates (by dropping less NAL units) and check if the green area becomes smaller. 
If this is the case, one reason for the green area that you are getting might be that the concealement algorithm is not powerful enough to conceal the error that you are making. 
That of course doesn't that the algorithm is not good, it rather means that your error is too much for it.

When I first experienced this, I was not aware of the rate of a normal error that the concealment algorithm of the JSVM was capable of handling.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. The slices option I am using from HM reference decoder is 'maximum slice size MTU 1500 bytes', this leads to uneven number of slices in any frame. Maximum and smaller slices in I frame, and sometimes 1 slice per frame for B and P. So, actually I have dropped a single NAL unit in this figure. If there was some option to remove that green overlay thing( as clearly the concealed background can be seen), I can proceed with my project. Thanks again.